# UIWebView got crashed on video streaming only on iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, ios8.4

I rendered videos in my app using UIWebView. Youtube video is streaming with no issues but videos from my server crashes the app. I got this issue after updating the iOS to 8.4 . It works fine with iOS 8.3 and other older versions.

Here is the crash log

> NSInvalidArgumentExceptionapplicationIsAdSheet
>   -[MPVideoView playbackState]: unrecognized selector sent to instance *****
>
> Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:0
>
> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:0objc_exception_throw
>
> Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:0
>
> Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:0
>
> Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:0CF_forwarding_prep_0
>
> Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer:0
>
> Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.webplugin/QuickTime
>   Plugin:0applicationIsAdSheet
>
> Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer:0
>
> Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer:0
>
> Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit:0
>
> Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit:0
>
> Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit:0
>
> Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit:0
>
> Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit:0
>
> Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation:0_NSFireDelayedPerform
>
> Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:0
>
> Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:0
>
> Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:0
>
> Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:0CFRunLoopRunSpecific
>
> Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:0CFRunLoopRunInMode
>
> PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices:0GSEventRunModal
>
> Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit:0UIApplicationMain
>
> MyApp/main.m:16:0main
>
> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib:0

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Yes it will crash always in iOS 8.4 . I replaced UIWebview with MPMoviePlayerViewController which works fine.

Comment: @Aravind Did you use presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated for presenting presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated ? is it working for you in IOS8.4  Adding player as subview working fine i tried . But presenting  MPMoviePlayerViewController for full screen videos is breaking only in IOS 8.4.

Comment: Yes i used presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated in iOS 8.4 . No issues till now